# NullPointerException while invoking mocked method using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I am getting `NPE` while mocking a mocked method. My understanding is that mock takes care of everything else as long as we invoke the method using mocked object.

Method under test

```
 public IDocumentSet sendDocuments(IClientUserDto cu, IDocumentSet ds) throws ESignatureProviderException {

    logMethodStartDebug(cu, CLASS_NAME, "sendDocuments(IClientUserDto, IDocumentSet)");

    IDocumentSet set = null;

    List<DocumentContent> documentContent = new ArrayList<DocumentContent>();
    Envelope env = new Envelope();
    MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart();
    String token = null;
    String envId = null;
    String status = null;

    try {           
        List<IDocumentDto> dtos = loadDocuments(cu, ds);
        List<IDocument> docs = ds.getDocuments();
        dtos = validateDocs(docs, dtos);

        ISendDocumentsTransformerArgs args = new SendDocumentsTransformerArgs(cu);
        args.setDocuments(docs);
        args.setDocumentDtos(dtos);
        args.setCallbackConfiguration(getConfiguration().getCallback());
        args.setModuleConfiguration(getModuleConfiguration());

        ITransformer transformer = new SendDocumentsRESTTransformer();
        ITransformerResult result = transformer.transformRequest(args);
```

JUnit test case

```
@RunWith( PowerMockRunner.class )
@PrepareForTest( {DtoUtils.class, ESignatureSpringUtil.class, AppContext.class, DocusignRESTUtil.class} )
public class TestDocusignRESTProvider {

private String accountId = "025f1a5d-b796-4ba6-85d2-b2a4a90d109c";
private String address;
private IClientUserDto iClientUserDto;
private IClientUserVendorDto iClientUserVendorDto ;
private ILoggingHandler iloggingHandler;
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
private DocusignRESTClient docusignRestClient;
private WebTarget webTarget;
private Response response;
private Invocation.Builder builder;     
private IDocumentSet iDocumentSet;
private IDocumentManager iDocumentManager;
private IProviderConfiguration iProviderConfiguration;
private ITransformer iTransformer;
private ITransformerResult iTransformerResult;
private IManager iManager;
private SendDocumentsTransformerArgs args;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    iClientUserDto = new ClientUserDto();
    iloggingHandler = mock( ILoggingHandler.class );
    applicationContext = mock( ApplicationContext.class );
    iClientUserVendorDto = mock( IClientUserVendorDto.class );
    docusignRestClient = mock( DocusignRESTClient.class );
    webTarget = mock( WebTarget.class );
    response = mock( Response.class );
    builder = mock( Invocation.Builder.class );
    iDocumentSet = mock( IDocumentSet.class );
    iDocumentManager = mock( IDocumentManager.class );
    iProviderConfiguration = mock( IProviderConfiguration.class );
    iTransformer = mock( ITransformer.class );
    iTransformerResult = mock( ITransformerResult.class );
    iManager = mock( IManager.class );
    args = mock( SendDocumentsTransformerArgs.class );
    PowerMockito.mockStatic( DtoUtils.class );
    PowerMockito.mockStatic( ESignatureSpringUtil.class );
    PowerMockito.mockStatic( AppContext.class );
    PowerMockito.mockStatic( DocusignRESTUtil.class );
}

@Test
public void testSendDocuments() throws Exception {
    AppContext.setApplicationContext( applicationContext );
    IClientUserDto iClientUserDto = mock( IClientUserDto.class );

    DocusignRESTProvider docusignRestProvider = new DocusignRESTProvider();
    docusignRestProvider.setLoggingHandler( iloggingHandler );
    docusignRestProvider.setDocumentManager( iDocumentManager );
    docusignRestProvider.setConfiguration( iProviderConfiguration );
    docusignRestProvider.setManager( iManager );

    Mockito.when( iloggingHandler.isGeneralDebugEnabled() ).thenReturn( Boolean.TRUE );
    Mockito.when( iTransformer.transformRequest( args ) ).thenReturn( iTransformerResult );
    docusignRestProvider.sendDocuments( iClientUserDto, iDocumentSet );
}
```

So, when the code reaches `transformer.transformRequest(args);` line it blows up. I am mocking the ITransformer and calling transformerRequest method on it, shouldn't that return me a mock object or I am doing it in a wrong way.

Comment: Can you please provide a stack trace?

Comment: Did you read my last comment, when you asked the same question yesterday?  It explained what you're doing wrong here.

Comment: @DavidWallace Probably not ... and just for the record; please have a look at my answer here; and feel free to give some feedback. As I assume I am addressing the problem behind his problem.

Comment: Why are you guys making a big deal out of this. This is just a simple question how to mock an object in this situation. I have to do this because this is my job whether I am wasting my time money whatever I have to do this. On what side you guys answer the simplest question but in this case this is not helpful this is this or that. Come on guys be practical.

Answer (score 1):

You are not mocking the  transformer object.

```
ITransformer transformer = new SendDocumentsRESTTransformer();
```

This line is creating actual object and not mock object. You need to instruct mockito to inject a mock object when new SendDocumentsRESTTransformer() is called. Use PowerMockito to do this.

PowerMockito.whenNew(SendDocumentsRESTTransformer.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(iTransformer);

Add this line in the test method before calling

```
docusignRestProvider.sendDocuments( iClientUserDto, iDocumentSet );
```

This will instruct Mockito to return a mock object when `new SendDocumentsRESTTransformer()` is called thus inside your `sendDocuments` method transformer is set to mock object.

Comment: Are you using Mockito API because I don't see whenNew() and withNoArguments() methods?

Comment: You are using PowerMockito. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Mockito does not have this feature of Mocking constructor call..  Use PowerMockito. PowerMockito.whenNew(SendDocumentsRESTTransformer.class).withNoArguments()

Comment: It is complaining to cast it to SendDocumentsRESTTransformer and it doesn't work if I make mock of SendDocumentsRESTTransformer and pass instead of iTransformer.

Comment: This is not working for me. It throws ClassCastException if I cast iTransformer to SendDocumentsRESTTransformer.

Comment: iTransformer = mock( SendDocumentsRESTTransformer.class ); PowerMockito.whenNew(SendDocumentsRESTTransformer.class).wit‌​hNoArguments().thenReturn(iTransformer); Is this not working for you? Can u put the StackTrace?

Comment: It's not mocking it. It is still giving me the same POJO but not the mocked one.

Comment: Have u added the class under @PrepareForTest?

Comment: Yes it's there. I got other static methods too so annotations are in place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141659/discussion-between-praneeth-ramesh-and-mike).

Answer (score 1):

Giving you a complete non-answer here: I think you are going down the wrong rabbit hole.

Any class that needs so many test settings as you are showing here is clearly violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Unit tests can only unfold their benefits when used for small, testable units of production code. But you need 10+ mocks, and to mock static methods in 4 classes in order to *setup* your testcases.

This is personal opinion, but based on a lot of experience: such tests do not help you. You spend **hours** to write test code that simply follows the implementation of your production code. You don't find bugs this way.

You only find that your unit test break whenever you have to change your production code. And worse: even the simplest refactoring might break such unit tests immediately. And when mocking static stuff, even a un-related change in another class has the potential to turn into a failing unit test elsewhere.

Such kind of unit tests do not help your work; to the contrary: they slow you down.

In other words: you shouldn't spend your time understanding why PowerMock is failing you here (because you did something wrong in your testcase). Instead you should do one of two things:

- If possible, re-design your production code. Look into [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) OO design; and start fixing the mess that was created so far! Learn how to write [testable](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) code instead.
- If that is not possible, then talk to the people who tell you to write such kind of unit tests. Do some research upfront; create statistics, like: how many bugs did you find with those tests (probably: 0). And then: convince your peers what the real problem is; and that writing such unit tests is (most likely) a waste of everybody's time and energy.

Meaning: unit tests are not written to achieve "100% coverage" or to allow putting a checkmark in some "has a unit test" spreadsheet.

They are written to verify your code; to help you find and fix bugs. And maybe I am wrong; but what you are showing here doesn't look like anything that falls into the "helpful" category.

Comment: When your boss comes and tells you to learn Mockito or PowerMock and start writing test cases for the services then you break any kind of rule whether it's OO or any other principle. You are probably in a position to say all these but not me. So let me learn and let me solve my issue.

Comment: I think you are missing my point: most likely, such kind of unit tests are a **bad** decision from a business point of view. Collect arguments; align with your peers; and present that input to your higher-ups. Business people usually understand it quickly when you show up "we are wasting money here". Of course, when you live in an environment where that isnt possible; that is hard. But keep in mind: answers here are not only written for the OP. But for anybody who comes by and that has a similar problem. And for the record: our team wrote unit tests like this before. They only ...

Comment: did cost time (== money!). There was never a return on that investment; just an endless series of "broken tests" again and again. In other words: this is not only about business value. It is also about you, the developer not going crazy. Just step back for a second. You learn all the skills to write these tests. And then, in 3 months, something breaks horribly. Your manager will turn to **you** and ask you: "But **you** wrote those unit tests? Why did your work not prevent this fail?" What are you going to tell him then? "Sorry boss, but the hours I spent on this were wasted!"

Answer (score 0):

Why are you mocking all the classes used in here? This is wrong and this is not a good practice in Junit. Mock service alone and do not mock transformers. Let the service return the xml or any object to transform and let the transformer do its job.Make sure the mock object is actually getting mocked. Debut the code and inspect the object. I the object is not mocked then it may throw a Null Pointer.

Comment: This has been resolved already. And, I am using PowerMock to return me a mocked object when it encounters new keyword. Why I am mocking so many objects is because of the fact that the service is complex, it is also a legacy code and there is so much going on.